# BITFIELD INVALID error with Discord Bot Build?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

So, I've mostly dabbled in coding only for my school homework and simple minecraft datapacks. The last time I've touched coding for any bot was high school, so what am I doing wrong? I followed a tutorial from 2022 verbatim, and this is the error I'm getting:

```
RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS.
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:172:11)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:167:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:167:40)
    at new BitField (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:33:38)
    at new IntentsBitField (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\IntentsBitField.js:9:1)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:494:25)
    at new Client (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\index.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}

Node.js v20.5.1
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR> node .
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:172
    throw new DiscordjsRangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
    ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILD.
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:172:11)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:167:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
BitField.js:9:1)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:494:25)
    at new Client (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\index.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}

Node.js v20.5.1
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR>

BitField.js:9:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RAZZR\index.js:5:16)lient.js:494:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14) {0)
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}
```

*AND, here is my code (from the tutorial)*:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const prefix = '!';

const client = new Discord.Client({
    allowedMentions: {
        parse: ['users', 'roles'],
        repliedUser: true,

    },
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "GUILD_PRESENCES",
        "GUILD_MEMBERS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS",
    ],

});


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("RAZZR is online!")

})
```

below that is the bot's key so obviously I won't include that. But it seems to be struggling with -GUILDS-. How can I fix that?

This is only just the code to turn the bot on and off, make sure it's online and active. So I didn't figure I'd have any issues. But maybe I slipped up and I'm missing my error?